# Changing the order of integration and Fubini's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

My understanding of Fubini's theorem is that one can conclude $$ \int_{b}^{\infty} \int_{a}^{\infty} f(x,y) \, dx \, dy = \int_{a}^{\infty} \int_{b}^{\infty} f(x,y) \, dy \, dx $$ if at least one of the iterated integrals converges absolutely.

But [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_integration_%28calculus%29#Basic_theorems) seems to state that there are additional conditions. I'm a bit confused.

**EDIT**:

Revisiting this question, I now realize that theorem II in that Wikipedia article is not Fubini's theorem.

It's basically a corollary of the following theorem:

> Assume that $f(x,y)$ is a continuous function defined for $a \le x <
> \infty$ and $b \le y \le c$. If $ \int_{a}^{\infty} f(x,y) \, dx$
>   converges uniformly on the closed interval $[b,c]$, then
>   $$\int_{b}^{c} \int_{a}^{\infty} f(x,y) \, dx \, dy =
> \int_{a}^{\infty} \int_{b}^{c} f(x,y) \, dy \, dx . $$

The above theorem and theorem II in that Wikipedia article can both be found in chapter XIII, section 3 of Serge Lang's textbook *Undergraduate Analysis*.

Answer (score 1):

Fubini's  theorem doesn't apply here because:

$$\int_1^\infty \int_1^\infty \left| \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\right|=\infty$$